# MySQL delete based on single criteria

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

I'm not sure how to phrase my question and therefore I struggled to find any answer.  My data looks something like this:

```
+------+-------+------------+----+
| id   | block | repetition | x  |
+------+-------+------------+----+
| 5223 | 1     | 1          | 15 |
| 5223 | 1     | 2          | 17 |
| 5223 | 1     | 3          | 16 |
| 5223 | 2     | 1          | 14 |
| 5223 | 2     | 2          | 15 |
| 6238 | 2     | 1          | 18 |
| 6238 | 2     | 2          | 20 |
| 6238 | 2     | 3          | 20 |  
| 6238 | 2     | 4          | 21 |
+------+-------+------------+----+
```

I would like to query the table to delete the entire block (column) if I detect x < than 15 (just an example).  In this example it should delete rows 4 and 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
delete t1
from your_table t1
inner join
(
    select id, block
    from your_table
    group by id, block
    having sum(x < 15) > 0
) t2 on t1.id = t2.id and t1.block = t2.block
```

You can use a *self-join* to extract the data you want to delete. When using the same table twice in a query you need to use alias names to distinguish the tables from each other. That is why I used the `t1` and `t2` alias names.

By joining, the result (that will be deleted) will only be the records that match the inner join.

### [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/934b2/2)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this script deletes EVERYTHING in the table?  I've tried it twice... I even copy and pasted your answer and just changed table names.

Comment: Hi juergen d.  Sorry to pester you again, but exactly the same happens when replacing count with sum.  Thanks again for your quick response!

Comment: can't be. The SQLFiddle works. Please check again and reproduce the error in the fiddle.

Comment: Now I see.  Thanks, copied the SQLFiddle and saw what happened.  My problem is that it deleted the entire block 2, even from a different id.  I would just like to delete (in the case of this example) all records associated with id 5223 and block 2, because of the x 14 in id 5223, block 2 repition 1.  I hope this makes sense?

Comment: Wow, you are a genius!  Thanks a lot!  Would you be so kind as to briefly explain the t1 and t2 parts?  I'm just a beginner.  Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks again.  Would it be possible to force MySQL to test the same criteria (x < 15), but only where x is the first entry in the block?  Even if the first repitition is number 2?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. You better ask another question and add example data and expected output.